# How to resume subprocess after my python script is closed and restarted?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a python script that calls a subprocess like this

```
process = subprocess.Popen('python', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The above code will open a python interpreter inside the existing python execution.
What I want to do is that: When I close the main python execution and restart it I want the previous subprocess to continue it self. I know this is possible because when I `print(process)` it says `subprocess object created at <0x00123abc>`

Is it posible to resume this object by saving it's state some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking no. When the parent process dies, ownership of the subprocess is given to init (1) but it is not possible to regain ownership from init anymore. It is also not possible to regain the io channels.

Your best bet is to use screen - assuming you are on a unix based system. It doesn't help on windows. Screen has a clever way of getting around this restriction by creating a daemon process that actually executes your process and passes its IO to you. When your screen "gui" exits, the daemon keeps running and the subprocess, in this case a python interpreter, stays alive and keeps talking to the daemon as it believes it is the console. You can then use a different screen command to reattach to this daemon from a different shell/process.

This is the dinosaur trick we had to use to keep our sessions alive on 80x24 ANSI terminals but it still works.